# Delete elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, for example

```
s={{1,3,2},{1,3,2},{2,3,1},{3,1},{2,3,1}};
c={{3},{1,2},{3}};
```

First element of `c` means that number 1 from `s[[3]]` must be deleted. Number is a position of this element in `c`.

Second element of `c`: delete number 2 from `s[[{1,2}]]`.

Third: delete number 3 from `s[[3]]`

The result must be

```
(* {{1,3},{1,3},{2},{3,1},{2,3,1}} *)
```

Another example

```
s={{2,1,3},{2,3,1},{1,2,3},{2,3}};
c={{1},{2,4},{3}};
(* {{2,3},{3,1},{1,2},{3}} *)
```

One more question. Also two lists:

```
s={{{1,3},{1,2},{3,2},{1},{3},{2}},
{{1,3},{1,2},{3,2},{1},{3},{2}},
{{1},{2},{3}},
{{3},{2},{1}}};
c={{3},{1,2},{}};
```

So, from `s[[3]]` `(* {{1},{2},{3}} *)` it's necessary to delete ALL elements which contain number 1: `{1} (* {{2},{3}} *)`

From `s[[{1,2}}]]` - all elements which contain number 2

```
(* {{{1,3},{1},{3}},
{{1,3},{1},{3}},
{{2},{3}},
{{3},{2},{1}}} *)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html), [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), and [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html).

### Delete Numbers

```
s1 = {{1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 3, 1}};
c1 = {{3}, {1, 2}, {3}};

MapIndexed[(s1[[#1]] = (s1[[#1]] /. {First@#2 -> Nothing})) &, c1];
s1

(* {{1, 3}, {1, 3}, {2}, {3, 1}, {2, 3, 1}} *)
```

### Delete Sublists

```
s2 = {
   {{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}, {1}, {3}, {2}},
   {{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}, {1}, {3}, {2}},
   {{1}, {2}, {3}},
   {{3}, {2}, {1}}
   };
c2 = {{3}, {1, 2}, {}};

MapIndexed[(s2[[#1]] = (s2[[#1]] /. {{___, First@#2, ___} -> Nothing})) &, c2];
s2

(*
{{1,3},{1},{3}}
{{1,3},{1},{3}}
{{2},{3}}
{{3},{2},{1}}
*)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if possible can you tell more about the aim of author who asked the question I have so much tried to understand your solution but I think I cannot understand the main question!

Comment: @Irreversible OP has a list of positions `c` and wants to perform some action on the list `s` that is a function of each position and the position's index in list of positions. `MapIndexed` is mapping its function over `c`. `MappedIndexed`'s function takes two arguments. The first is the item from the list it is mapping over (`#1`) and the second is the index of that item in the list (`#2`). `#1` is obtained from the list. While `#2` is generated by the system for you; you don't need to provide it.  Try `MapIndexed[{#1,#2}&, Range[6,10]]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. OP has used of phrases such as : Number 1 Number 2!!! they are not defined in `list-manipulation` category. I wish a professional OP edits his/her question.

Answer (score 4):

`Do` and `DeleteCases` can do what you want

The first one:

```
delete[s_, c_] := Module[{s0 = s},
  Do[s0[[c[[i]]]] = DeleteCases[s0[[c[[i]]]], i, 2], {i, Length@c}];
  s0
  ]
```

The second one

```
delete2[s_, c_] := Module[{s0 = s},
  Do[s0[[c[[i]]]] = DeleteCases[s0[[c[[i]]]], {___, i, ___}, 2], {i, 
    Length@c}];
  s0
  ]
```